# Transport sendMessage doesn't throw exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail, transport

I send message to invalid email address, but I doesn't get any exception. It works like everything is good, and in debugger it shows as everything is normal.

```
private MailService() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    props.put("mail.smtps.host", HOST);
    props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.from", FROM);
    props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
}

public static void sendMessage(String recipient, String subject,
        String message) throws MessagingException {

    if (mailService == null) {
        mailService = new MailService();
    }

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
    mimeMessage.setSender(new InternetAddress(FROM));
    mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/plain");

    mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect(HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD);

    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage,
            mimeMessage.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();

}
```

I tried for different email addresses, and for all it didn't throw exception. What do I wrong ?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "invalid"? Can you give an example? An email address which doesn't happen to have a mailbox isn't the same as one which is syntactically invalid, for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: any stupid address, example: w.e@w1234 , I also tried to send email from mail, and obviously it says invalid email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TransportListener won't tell you anything more than an exception will tell you.  The real answer to your question is in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr).

Comment: thanks I understand, why excpetion doesn't come. Can you tell me, how can I fix that ?

Comment: Yes, I have read. I mean isn't it possible to know somehow if my mail was sent or not ?

Comment: It's possible to know whether the server accepted your message and will try to deliver it.  In general, it's not possible to know whether the message was ever **actually** delivered.

Comment: @BillShannon -- If JavaMail could act as an MTA for itself and deliver directly to MX servers, then changes that occurred between 2008-2010 related to SPF and the SMTP specs have allowed MX servers to begin issuing negative acknowledgement of recipient address either after the "RCPT TO" (e.g., Google) or "DATA" (e.g., Yahoo) verbs.

Comment: @BillShannon -- See, e.g., the discussion of RFC changes here: http://www.dontbouncespam.org/

Comment: @derekm - Creating an entire MTA is a tremendous amount of work.  Embedding an MTA inside a library used to talk to mail servers would be very complicated.  And still the problem is that not all servers will support whatever mechanism is designed to provide acknowledgement of delivery.  If you only care about users on the popular public mail servers, you might be able to come up with a "good enough" solution.  If you really need to know whether the address is valid, you need the recipient to click on a link in the message, or something like that.

Comment: We recently wrote the 1st layer of an MTA to probe MXes for rejections. I implemented the MX resolution algorithm (RFC 5321, section 5.1 "Locating the Target Host") & SMTP up to "RCPT TO", to confirm recipient nack on modern hosts. It was surprisingly little code, and I'm fully RFC-compliant. I was forced to do this thanks to cloud-based providers' strict reject/bounce rate requirements. I validate the recipient this way before sending the message on to JavaMail. If JavaMail did more of this itself, I could also get the nack on DATA. As time goes on, more servers will reject instead of bounce.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an TransportListener, which is attached to your transport-instance:
**adding TransportListener**

```java
transport.addTransportListener(new MyTransportListener());
```

**MyTransportListener.java**

```java
public class MyTransportListener implements TransportListener{

    @Override
    public void messageDelivered(TransportEvent te) {
        System.out.println("Everything went fine!");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageNotDelivered(TransportEvent te) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + te.getMessage());
        Address[] invalidAddresses = te.getInvalidAddresses();
        Address[] validUnsentAddresses = te.getValidUnsentAddresses();
        //make something happen
    }

    @Override
    public void messagePartiallyDelivered(TransportEvent te) {
        messageNotDelivered(te);
    }

}
```

I din't try this (yet), but I think this is exactly what you need...
**EDIT**
I was wrong, this won't help with your problem

Comment: Thanks, I tried your advise. But the problem is that it says "Everything went fine!" when email address doesn't exists.

Comment: so the mailserver you are connected to, is not verifying the adresses. The answer from Bill Shanon helps to understand this issue

Comment: I understand, but how can I fix that ?

Comment: you can't fix this issue, because this problem is not javaMail-specific. If the server transports your mail without an error, there is (as I understand) no way that your implementation can track the way and status of your message furthermore. The JavaMail-FAQ suggests to read this document, maybe this make it more clear: http://cr.yp.to/proto/verp.txt

Comment: I see, but doesn't it exist the way to know mail was sent or not ?